# How does the Firebase Cloud Functions instance Lifecycle look like? does my caching even make sense?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-functions

This is my caching mechanism to "make sure" that I don't have to connect to mongoDB several times.

```
let cachedClient
async function makeDB()  {
    if (cachedClient) {
        return cachedClient.db('invoice')
    }
    cachedClient = await client.connect()
    return cachedClient.db('invoice')
}
```

However I am working with firebase cloud functions and I am not sure about how they work under the hood, I can not imagine that an instance is being tore down after each execution, because setting up a new one with a whole environment would take a bit.
Is there a time to live for each function instance?
Should I implement this caching mechanism in the global scope outside of the function?
Could there be a big problem with reusing the same client for various users? (Performance wise)

Comment: Have you thought about using a cdn?